# Arm deformation problem

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

My rig has a problem that makes it deform strangely when i try to move the arm from side to side, it also does this when i try to rotate it.
[image]

i figure it would probabaly be because i does not have enough edges adding loopcuts and subdividing is not working what should i do?

[image]

Comment: You will probably need driven shapekeys. BUT, first fix your topology, quads work best when they are square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Edit mode select the *Arm_Top.R.001* (the left top arm) and set the Transform: Roll to 0.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most rigs have 2 forearm bones to help with the rotation problem... more quads wouldn't help in this case as for the bending action very careful manual weight painting will make a much better transition... also try to look into corrective shape keys... they are basically regular shape keys driven by a driver which is linked to the rotation of the bone... so when the arm bends the bicep bulges and the pinching in the corner can be tweaked... hope this helps .... it's also worth mentioning that quads work best when they are as close to being square as possible

Comment: it has a wrist already so i tried adding a secong forearm bone by subdividing it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: tried reapllying automatic wrights and my mesh started to stretch everywhere